# Kendo ui dropdownlist remove specific item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-datasource

I have a dropdownlist that I fill from a datasource. After a specific event, I want to remove one item from my dropdownlist with `id = 22`.  (I know it's weird and hardcoding but not much time for a newbie left). Is that possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

This is a quick and dirty way to accomplish the task using the Kendo DataSource remove method.  It assumes your drop down is bound to an object containing a property called "id".  If you're using the standard text/value key value pair object, then replace the if statement with `if (item.Value == 22)`.

```
var dropdown = $('#dropDownId').data("kendoDropDownList");

var raw = dropdown.dataSource.data();
var length = raw.length;

var item, i;
for(i=length-1; i>=0; i--){

  item = raw[i];
  if (item.id == 22) {
    dataSource.remove(item);
    break;
  }

}
```

Source: http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/13-01-29/adding_and_removing_items_in_kendo_data_datasource

Comment: Good morning!

I reall need a quick a dirty way for right now. Thank you all very much for your answers! I will try it out right now!!

Thaaaaaank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent of this item and then remove it as a child of parent:

```
  document.getElementById("22").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("22"));
```

`getElementById("22")` gets an element which has id "22"

`parentNode` is parent of an element. In your case, it is dropdown

`removeChild(document.getElementById("22"))` removes the specified child from its patent. In your case, an element which has id "22".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Why?

Comment: If you're replying by code sample, at least explain why it solves the problem. "Answering" the question means not only giving instructions how to solve problem but also to educate asker what he have done wrong and what he needs to fix.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk In that case, has he *done* anyhing?

Comment: No, he hasn't done anything. But if you want for your answer to be complete, please explain what are you doing, for example that you're accessing parentNode of selected element and then removing itself by passing exact same object to removeChild. You know, your code answers question for asker, but there are others which will read this question in the future and you should provide information for those outside the context.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Edited. Good now?

Comment: Yes, that's much better. Mods will probably dispute my flag now, but for good reason. :)

Comment: Hello and thank you all for your help. I am more then satisfied with your answers. I will try it out and inform you. I am new (very new) in Kendo and wanted to know if it is possible just to remove hide one element. I was exhausted last night and that is the reason why I answer now. I dont have parent childs:  
drop-down-list 
k-data-source="List"
k-option-label="'Choose'"
k-data-text-field="'text'" 
k-data-value-field="'id'"

Comment: This has to be done in the dataSource as explained in nicael answer.